# Linking libraries with same symbol not producing error

Tags: c++

Discussing with a colleague, we came to an issue that we cannot resolve. Imagine I have a library that uses a function that by design we do not want to expose through the library headers. Since it will be used only in a single cpp file, we decided to place that function in the cpp file where it will be used. However, since this library will be used by other people we were concerned about what would happen if another library would define a function with the same name and the same signature. For this reason we have done a small test with two libraries and a main as the code below:

lib1.hpp

```
#pragma once

void myCoolFunction1();
```

lib1.cpp

```
#include "lib1.hpp"
#include <iostream>

inline void printMyCoolFunction1()
{
  std::cout << "My cool function 1 inline" << std::endl;
}
static void printMyCoolFunction2()
{
  std::cout << "My cool function 1 static" << std::endl;
}
void printMyCoolFunction3()
{
  std::cout << "My cool function 1" << std::endl;
}

void myCoolFunction1()
{
  printMyCoolFunction1();
  printMyCoolFunction2();
  printMyCoolFunction3();
}
```

lib2.hpp

```
#pragma once

void myCoolFunction2();
```

lib2.cpp

```
#include "lib2.hpp"
#include <iostream>

inline void printMyCoolFunction1()
{
  std::cout << "My cool function 2 inline" << std::endl;
}
static void printMyCoolFunction2()
{
  std::cout << "My cool function 2 static" << std::endl;
}

void printMyCoolFunction3()
{
  std::cout << "My cool function 2" << std::endl;
}

void myCoolFunction2()
{
  printMyCoolFunction1();
  printMyCoolFunction2();
  printMyCoolFunction3();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "lib1.hpp"
#include "lib2.hpp"

int main()
{
  myCoolFunction1();
  myCoolFunction2();
  return 0;
}
```

And a corresonding cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( test_cpp )

add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)

add_library(lib1 SHARED src/lib1.cpp src/lib1.hpp)
target_link_libraries(lib1 stdc++)
add_library(lib2 SHARED src/lib2.cpp src/lib2.hpp)
target_link_libraries(lib2 stdc++)
add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main lib1 lib2)
```

Compiling this does not give any warning (tested with: clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2, g++-9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 9.4.0 and g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0) but when executing the main file, the output shows that only the static function of the library 2 was colled, the calls to the other two functions that have the same name and signature between library 1 and 2 were called from library 1 from within library 2.

Output:

```
My cool function 1 inline
My cool function 1 static
My cool function 1
My cool function 1 inline
My cool function 2 static
My cool function 1
```

Does anybody have a good explanation on:

1. Why is the compiler/linker not complaining about symbols already defined?
2. Why are the compilers using the inline function of the other library in library 2?
3. What is `static` doing behind the scenes so the behaviour is the expected (or our expeced) one?
4. Is using `static` in these types of functions a good design? Or how should we "hide" functions from the public API of our library?

Comment: When building shared libraries, you should hide everything by default, and expose only what you intend to expose. Look up `-fvisibility=hidden` and `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`.

Comment: "the output shows that only the static function of the library 2 was called".  Don't tell us this.  Show us the actual output.  Because your explanation is ambiguous.  Did that mean "of the static functions, only the one in library 2 was called" (which I don't believe) or "of the functions in library 2, only the static one was called" (which is not how I first understood you, but is expected)?

Comment: Also, this is C++ not C, so you should use namespaces and then this problem will completely disappear

Comment: Thank you all for your responses and comments. We now understand a bit more about what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you would expect an error. A shared library is a linked
entity itself. This means the final .DLL or .so has finalised relative addresses for its symbols, and the generated code of the library "knows" exactly what is where.

However, a static library is merely an archive of object files. There is no linkage involved in making it. Therefore, in your two scenarios, you are doing two different things. In the case of two shared libraries, the linker is invoked 3 times, but for the other one only once.

When you try to invoke the linker only once (static libraries) it has two options for the function. But using two shared libraries you already have the linker "to decide" about the addresses (that is unless you explicitly allow unresolved symbols in your shared library)

**Update:**

I re-created your example on Windows. Apart from default export behaviour, the basics are the same. First, let's see what happens in the case of two shared libraries. Each one has only one exported symbol. `lib1.dll` contains:

```
?myCoolFunction1@@YAXXZ, 0x0000114F
```

and `lib2.dll` contains:

```
?myCoolFunction2@@YAXXZ, 0x0000100F
```

As you can see, the shared libraries are "finalised" in terms of address resolution. It means the linker has already decided on where to find internal functions, calculated the addresses and generated code that uses those addresses. You can see that in the generated assembly code:

```
$LN3:
push    rdi
sub rsp, 32                 
call    ?printMyCoolFunction1@@YAXXZ    ; printMyCoolFunction1
call    ?printMyCoolFunction2@@YAXXZ    ; printMyCoolFunction2
call    ?printMyCoolFunction3@@YAXXZ    ; printMyCoolFunction3
add rsp, 32
pop rdi
ret 0
```

Addresses like `?printMyCoolFunction1@@YAXXZ` are defined earlier. All are relative to the entire library.

Then you link your executable against `lib1.lib`. The linker looks only for `myCoolFunction1()` and finds it at the export table. The offsets and addresses are re-calculated and linkage is done. There is no need to know the address of `printMyCoolFunction1`, `printMyCoolFunction2` and `printMyCoolFunction3` at this time because the code that calls them is already generated in the DLL. The only imports for executable are:

```
Import from module lib1.dll :
         Function ?myCoolFunction1@@YAXXZ, 0x0000E908
Import from module lib2.dll :
         Function ?myCoolFunction2@@YAXXZ, 0x0000E92C
```